# Chart with dynamic points (combined wind speed and direction)

Tags: thingsboard

In thingsboard, (how) can I use a dynamic character and colour as the points in a time series while using data from a different series as parameters?

What I am trying to achieve is a combined historic wind speed and direction chart like this:

[image]

I have two data sources:

- Wind speed in km/h
- Wind direction in degrees (0 is north, 180 is south)

The colour is based on wind speed and calculated by a static rule (e.g above 30km/h is displayed in red)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this is not possible with the thingsboard charts (`TbFlot`). They seem to act as the (very handy) glue between the widget configuration and the [underlying chart-library called Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/).

However, you can use the `flot` library directly from your widgets!
Just call

```
$.plot(self.ctx.$container, [[[0,0], [1,1], [2,1]]]);
```

to draw a chart.

I stumbled uppon some code in the [flot documentation about customizing the data series](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-data-series) and came up with this to make it work as a thingsboard widget:

```
self.onInit = function() {
    let counter, f_drawCross, flotOptions;

    counter = 0;

    f_drawCross = function(ctx, x, y, radius, shadow) {
        var size = radius * Math.sqrt(Math.PI) * 2;

        if (shadow) {
            return;
        }

        if (++counter % 2) {
            ctx.moveTo(x - size, y);
            ctx.lineTo(x + size, y);
            ctx.moveTo(x, y + size);
            ctx.lineTo(x, y - size);
        }
        else {
            ctx.moveTo(x - size, y - size);
            ctx.lineTo(x + size, y + size);
            ctx.moveTo(x - size, y + size);
            ctx.lineTo(x + size, y - size);
        }
    };

    flotOptions = {
        series: {
            lines: { show: true },
            points: {
                show: true,
                symbol: f_drawCross
            }
        }
    };

    $.plot(self.ctx.$container, [[[0,0], [1,1], [2,1]]], flotOptions);
};
```

It creates a chart in your widget container and draws (alternating) crosses as the data points. I think you will need some kind of counter/index to let the drawing method access the values of the current data point it is painting.